# Using logic laws to verify the logical equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I need to use theorem 2.1.1 in order to verify the following:

∼((∼p ∧ q) ∨ (∼ p ∧ ∼q)) ∨ (p ∧ q) ≡ p

I applied the Double Negative Law to get

((p ∧ q) ∨ (∼p ∧ ∼q)) ∨ (p ∧ q)

I noticed we have (p ∧ q) twice, which is redundant so I applied the Idempotent law to get:

(p ∧ q) ∨ (∼p ∧ ∼q)

not sure if that was the correct step. But from this point I get lost. Essentially this is saying p and q or not p and not q.

If anyone can let me know if I am going in the right direction and any help regarding what to do next, it would be greatly appreciated. I have been trying to solve this myself for a while now and haven't been able to get past this point.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLFhe.png)

Comment: $$∼((∼p ∧ q) ∨ (∼ p ∧ ∼q)) ∨ (p ∧ q) ≡ ∼(∼p ∧(q∨ ∼q ))≡∼∼p ≡p$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ∼((∼p ∧ q) ∨ (∼ p ∧ ∼q)) ∨ (p ∧ q) ≡ p
>
> I applied the Double Negative Law to get
>
> ((p ∧ q) ∨ (∼p ∧ ∼q)) ∨ (p ∧ q)

You have to negate everything in the brackets following the negation symbol, not just the first term.

$\neg\underline{((\neg p ∧ q) ∨ (\neg p ∧ \neg q))} ∨ (p ∧ q)$

Apply deMorgan's

${(\neg\underline{(\neg p ∧ q)} \land \neg\underline{(\neg p ∧ \neg q)})} ∨ (p ∧ q)$

Again

${((\neg\neg p \lor \neg q) \land (\neg\neg p \lor \neg\neg q))} ∨ (p ∧ q)$

Now apply Double Negation

${((p \lor \neg q) \land (p \lor q))} ∨ (p ∧ q)$

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is not correct.  There is no double negation there, since the first negation is the negation of the disjunction of $\neg p \land q$ and $\neg p \land \neg q$

However, whenever you have such a negation (a negation of a disjunction), you can do DeMorgan. Do you see how that works in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step:

$$\begin{align}
\lnot((\lnot p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)) \lor (p \land q) & ≡ \text{ [de Morgan]} \\
(\lnot(\lnot p \land q) \land \lnot(\lnot p \land \lnot q)) \lor (p \land q) & ≡ \text{ [de Morgan]} \\
((\lnot\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \land (\lnot\lnot p \lor \lnot\lnot q)) \lor (p \land q) & ≡ \text{ [double neg]} \\
((p \lor \lnot q) \land (p \lor q)) \lor (p \land q) & ≡ \text{ [distributivity]} \\
(p \lor (\lnot q \land q)) \lor (p \land q) & ≡ \text{ [complementation]} \\
(p \lor 0) \lor (p \land q) & ≡ \text{ [identity for disjunction]} \\
p \lor (p \land q) & ≡ \text{ [identity for conjunction]} \\
(p\land 1) \lor (p \land q) & ≡ \text{ [distributivity]} \\
p\land (1 \lor q) & ≡ \text{ [annihilation]} \\
p\land 1 & ≡ \text{ [identity]} \\
p & \ \ \ \text{  [q.e.d]}\\
\end{align}$$